# How to get the tasks list in GCD queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

I get the main queue in GCD as below and I add different tasks from different classes in my apps.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue (
    DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Now I want to know how many of my tasks which are still in the GCD main queue.

Is there any method to get the tasks list in GCD queue?

Thanks

Comment: GCD tag is reserved for "greatest common divisor" - changed tag to correct one.

Answer (score 4):

That's really not the paradigm of GCD.  If you want to keep track of a certain group of operations, for example, you can create a dispatch group and sign up to be notified when it is done, as in this example.

```
dispatch_group_t taskGroup = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = //Get whatever queue you want here
dispatch_group_async(taskGroup, queue, ^ {
    [object doSomething];
});
dispatch_group_async(taskGroup, queue, ^ {
    [object doMoreStuff];
});
dispatch_group_async(taskGroup, queue, ^ {
    [object doEvenMoreStuff];
});
dispatch_group_notify(taskGroup, queue, ^{
    [object workDone];
});
dispatch_release(taskGroup);
```

Comment: Sorry that dispatch group could not be applied in my apps. As multiple classes would add multiple tasks to GCD queue. Dispatch group seems to only applied to a single instance of a class. My situation is that I want to monitor the tasks from multiple classes in a central pool in global level.

Comment: Shouldn't you use dispatch_group_release inside the dispatch_group_notify block instead of dispatch_release under it?

Comment: The queue will retain the group, so it is safe to release after you are done adding things to it (or I have made a horrible mistake and the application will not function ^^;)

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is done with dispatch groups rather than queues. You can assign tasks to a group using `dispatch_group_async()`, or you can manually mark things in the group using `dispatch_group_enter()` and `dispatch_group_leave()`. You can then check for whether there is anything in the group using either `dispatch_group_notify()` or `dispatch_group_wait()`.

Comment: Sorry that dispatch group could not be applied in my apps. As multiple classes would add multiple tasks to GCD queue. Dispatch group seems to only applied to a single instance of a class. My situation is that I want to monitor the tasks from multiple classes in a central pool in global level.

Comment: Groups are added at the point of dispatch. It has nothing to do with classes. Are you using `NSOperations` rather than directly calling `dispatch_` methods? If you're using `dispatch_` methods, then you can apply a group at that point.

Comment: My situation: class A, class B and class C would add tasks to GCD inside their own instances. How can I create a common dispatch group for the different classes? Can I pass a created group into different classes? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. It's just a dispatch_group_t. That's a type, and can be passed as parameters, assigned to variables or ivars. You need to retain and release it using dispatch_retain and dispatch_release.